# Remove all special characters from the end of a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently developing an app which requires multiple special characters at the end of the string.

Some examples are:

1. 5 * + -
2. 345-+
3. ABC+-++

etc.

I would like to replace all these as follows:

1. 5*+- to 5A
2. 345-+ to 345A
3. ABC+-++ to ABCA

Can someone help me in doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you have done so far

Comment: [The article on regular expressions from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) should help you get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the String.prototype.replace() method.

```
var str = 'Your string';
var regex = 'Your regex';
str.replace(regex, 'replaced by this string');
```

Answer (score 1):

Java version of code:

```
    String myName ="5 ABCD898* + -";
        char[] line = myName.toCharArray();
        for(int i = line.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if (!((line[i] >= 'a' && line[i]<='z') || (line[i] >= 'A' && line[i]<='Z')||(line[i] >= '0' && line[i]<='9')))
        {
            line[i] = ' ';
        }else{
break;}
    }
    myName=String.valueOf(line).trim()+"A";
System.out.println(myName);
```

other version of code

```
string line="5 * + -";

for(int i = line.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if (!((line[i] >= 'a' && line[i]<='z') || (line[i] >= 'A' && line[i]<='Z')||(line[i] >= '0' && line[i]<='9')))
        {
            line[i] = '\0';
        }else{
break;}
    }
line+="A";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.prototype.replace()` with callback which will help you modify the string

```js
const inputs = ['5*+-', '345-+', 'ABC+-++'];

const results = inputs.map(s => {
  const specialChr =  /[^A-Za-z0-9 ].*/g;
  const output = s.replace(specialChr, function (matched, index, original) {
    return matched + original.slice(0, index) + 'A';
  });
  return output;
});
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

Fastest for you, `split` on `first special char` and get the `first`.

`const clean = (str) => str.split(/\W/)[0]+"A"`

```js
const clean = (str) => str.split(/\W/)[0]+"A"

const data  = `5*+- to 5A
345-+ to 345A
ABC+-++ to ABCA`.split("\n")

data.forEach(line => console.log(clean(line)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by "special characters".  I'd suggest a RegEx approach.  Start off by looking at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)